# Return the string based on the source via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a img source on my page with no tag id to select it and would like to regex match to it and return the full URL.

The img looks like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">
<img src="https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/pagview?aasdasd"style="display:none" width="0" height="0">
</div>
```

I have tried the following JS:

```
var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var target;
for(var i = 0, max = allImages.length; i < max; i++)
if (allImages[i].src =~ "https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/"){
   target = allImages[i];
   break;
}
console.log(allImages)
```

what I would like to do is have a script to iterate through all images and if the scr url contains suburl2, return the full src url.

hopefully that all makes sense.... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` within attribute equals, attribute begins with or attribute contains selector to select `<img>` element having `src` attribute equal to `"https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/pagview?aasdasd"`

```js
 var img = document.querySelector("img[src='https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/pagview?aasdasd']");
console.log(img.src);
```

```html
<div style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/pagview?aasdasd" style="display:none" width="0" height="0">
</div>
```

Comment: hi there, the issue is that the URL is dynamic and change so i need to substring match it

Comment: @paco Does the `<img>` `src` always begin with `"https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/"`?

Comment: @paco Try attribute begins with selector `var img = document.querySelector("img[src^='https://suburl2.suburl1.url.com/c2/xyz/']");`

Comment: one more question is how do I manipulate that into a string.... basically the I have a string after the '?' in the source url "/pagview?aasdasd" and I only want those strings. I was going to substring index of type of function to it as a variable

Comment: @paco Try `var src = img.src; var str = src.slice(.indexOf("?") + 1, src.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get img src path

```
$('div img').attr('src')
```